# "GSAP target not found" in react.js and animation happens on its own on hot reload

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I'm trying to animate an element with `gsap` in `react.js`.

My code works only when react hot reloads and in console I have warning from gsap saying `GSAP target not found`

```
const FeaturedText = () => {
  const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    animation(tl);
  }, []);
  return <S.FeaturedText className="tl">Hi! Some Text</S.FeaturedText>;
};

const animation = (tl) => {
  tl.from(".tl", {
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1,
    x: 100,
    ease: "elastic",
    delay: 2,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we need to get access to the element that we want to animate.

> In react we use `useRef` hook to get a component's reference and then
> use gsap to animate it.

I'll explain how to animate a component in react properly.

```
  //initialize useRef
  let featuredText = useRef(null);

  //start animation only when dom components are mounted.
  useEffect(() => {
    const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: 0 });
    animation(tl, featuredText);
  }, []);

  //Animation
  const animation = (tl, el) => {
    tl.from(el, {
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 1,
      x: 100,
      ease: "elastic",
      delay: 2,
    });
  };

  //Component to be animated
  return (
    <S.FeaturedText ref={(el) => (featuredText = el)} className="tl">
      Hi! I'm Raghav
    </S.FeaturedText>
  );
```